# passing shell variable into parameter in shell script

Tags: shell, variables

I'm running this command to find the mounted network folder :

```
df | awk '/andi@192.168.1.10/ { print $1 }'
```

This code is working fine but rather using 'andi' i want to pass it using 'USER' variable. It showing the correct value if I echo the USER var.

> echo $USER
>
> > andi

But it's not working when I used the var . Seems the single quot pair is not working with $VAR :

```
df | awk '/$USER@192.168.1.10/ { print $1 }'
```

How should I use the var in this case ?

Comment: Something like `awk -v user=$USER '$1 ~ user {print $1}'` will make the `bash` variable into an `awk` variable.

Comment: ... though you'd probably want to define a field separator to split username from mount, i.e. `awk -F@ ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out, parameter expansion is not performed between single quotes. Hence `$USER` must be outside of single quotes, while `$1` must be inside:

```
df | awk /$USER@192.168.1.10/' { print $1 }'
```

To cope for the possibility, that the name stored on `USER` contains a space, you could alternatively write it as

```
df | awk "/$USER@192.168.1.10/"' { print $1 }'
```

since parameter expansion is done within double quotes. Just make sure that `awk` sees the program as **single** parameter. Therefore we can't have a space in front of the opening single quote.